# Is there a tool to view azure data factory logs?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I setup logging in an azure data factory pipeline for a copy activity.

The logs are written to an azure blob container.
This however generates a lot of separate folders, each containing a log file.
(this pipeline is triggered every x minutes)

[image]

Does a tool exist to make this more readable?
For example concatenate the logs (preserving the order)

Or is there another way to use these logfiles?

Comment: Azure data factory could probably read those logs and transform them ;)

Answer (score 1):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-log#the-schema-of-the-log-file), You can use multiple analysis engines to further analyze the log files.

There are a few examples below to use SQL query to analyze the log file by importing csv log file to SQL database.

**1.    Give me the copied file list.**

```
select OperationItem from SessionLogDemo where Message like '%File is successfully copied%'
```

**2.    Give me the file list copied within a particular time range.**

```
select OperationItem from SessionLogDemo where TIMESTAMP >= '<start time>' and TIMESTAMP <= '<end time>' and Message like '%File is successfully copied%'
```

**3.    Give me a particular file with its copied time and metadata.**

```
select * from SessionLogDemo where OperationItem='<file name>'
```

**4.    Give me a list of files with their metadata copied within a time range.**

```
select * from SessionLogDemo where OperationName='FileRead' and Message like 'Start to read%' and OperationItem in (select OperationItem from SessionLogDemo where TIMESTAMP >= '<start time>' and TIMESTAMP <= '<end time>' and Message like '%File is successfully copied%')
```

**5.    Give me the skipped file list.**

```
select OperationItem from SessionLogDemo where OperationName='FileSkip'
```

**6.    Give me the reason why a particular file skipped.**

```
select TIMESTAMP, OperationItem, Message from SessionLogDemo where OperationName='FileSkip'
```

**7.    Give me the list of files skipped due to the same reason: "blob file does not exist".**

```
select TIMESTAMP, OperationItem, Message from SessionLogDemo where OperationName='FileSkip' and Message like '%UserErrorSourceBlobNotExist%'
```

**8.    Give me the file name that requires the longest time to copy.**

```
select top 1 OperationItem, CopyDuration=DATEDIFF(SECOND, min(TIMESTAMP), max(TIMESTAMP)) from SessionLogDemo group by OperationItem order by CopyDuration desc
```

Comment: Thank you! I see in order to use this the logs need to be imported to an sql database. Are there any guidelines on how to do this? Would you use another pipeline?